# CRC-16 Computation in IEEE 802.11b

Tags: matlab, checksum, verilog, wifi

I would like to understand the CRC compuation in the Header field of IEEE 802.11b PHY. I read in the literature, CRC-16 is used and the 1's compliment of the reminder of the (e SIGNAL, SERVICE, and LENGTH by Generator Polynomial)

But I want to understand, given a bit stream, how this computation is done.

I am trying to understand, how to implement in Hardware using Shift registers or in Matlab.

Any suggestions or useful pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Thanks,

Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xilinx has an [app note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp209.pdf) and source code for the CRC in IEEE 802.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was successful in implementing it in simulink-.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an [article](http://outputlogic.com/my-stuff/circuit-cellar-january-2010-crc.pdf) on CRC generation for hardware description languages (Verilog , VHDL)

Comment: Thanks a ton for sharing, would saved few hours of scratching my head. I implemented the model in Simulink in Matlab :)